# comparing 2 vectors of different sizes c++

Tags: c++, vector

Basically, I have a vector of chars and an vector of lines, I want to compare the chars to the lines and if every single char in the vector can find a match in the vector of lines. it prints the position, for example. if the vector of lines is ABCDEF,HIJKL and the vector of chars is C,E,F,C the program prints 0,2 0,4 0,5 0,2

I've tried doing this myself but i've run into 2 problems, one. the vector of chars gets printed out of order, and two. if there is an element in the vector of chars that appears twice then it only prints the position once.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6McM.png

That is the output
the message file is THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE, this is the file that gets put into a char vector.

the book file is

ABCDE FG

HIJKLMNO

PQRSTUVWXYZ

and each line gets put into the vector of lines

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    string str;
    vector <string> bookVector;
    vector <char> messageVector;
    char c;
    ifstream message(argv[2]);
    ifstream book(argv[1]);
    ofstream outputFile(argv[3], ios::in | ios::binary);

    while (getline(book, str))
    {
        bookVector.push_back(str);
    }

    while (message.get(c))
    {
        messageVector.push_back(c);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bookVector.size(); i++) 
        for (int x = 0; x < bookVector[i].size(); x++) 
            if (find(messageVector.begin(), messageVector.end(), 
                     bookVector[i][x]) != messageVector.end()) {
                cout << "found a match at " << bookVector[i][x] <<
                        " at positions "<<i<<","<<x<< endl;
            }
}
```

Comment: *"the vector of chars gets printed out of order"* - you never print it. And did you want your code to care about the duplicate characters and **their** positions in it? - because currently, it does not. Look closer, both `i` and `x` are indices to `bookVector`, i.e. row and column. You never iterate through `messageVector`.

Comment: I want my code to care about duplicate characters and their positions yes, and im sorry I meant It prints the characters in bookVector that match the critera.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> book = { {"ABC"},{"DEF"},{"GHI"}, {"BFG"}, {"HELLO"} };
    std::vector<char> chars = { 'B', 'G', 'H' };

    for (int j = 0; j < chars.size(); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < book.size(); i++)
        {
            size_t offset = 0;
            while ((offset = book[i].find(chars[j], offset)) != std::string::npos)
            {
                std::cout << "Found " << chars[j] << " at " << i << "," << offset << std::endl;
                ++offset;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Output generated from the above example:

```
Found B at 0,1
Found B at 3,0
Found G at 2,0
Found G at 3,2
Found H at 2,1
Found H at 4,0
```

Comment: thank you! Could you tell me how to make it so that it chooses a random B coordinate G coordinate and H coordinate out of the same letter coordinates available instead of printing multiple?

Comment: To anyone who comes along to nag about this being a code-only answer, please first ask yourself, "What in this code needs explanation?"

Comment: If you only want to print a randomly chosen coordinate for a certain character, you could store all the coordinates which the character was found at in some container. When all coordinates have been found for a certain character you can just randomly select one of the stored coordinates.

Comment: what I was thinking of doing was to get all the characters that have the same row and offset, put it in a container, roll random from those elements. print the leftover position to the output file,  clear the container and move on to the next letter and do it all over again, however I do not know how to modify the while loop to do the part where I put the same positions in a container, once that is done I can do the rest myself. I know this is a lot to ask but if its possible could you walk me through that part?